# WordPress User roles/rights

Tags: wordpress, roles, categories, user-management, rights

I'm searching (a) plug-ins for user role and rights. My idea is to have an user geek1 which can only manage the the maincategory 'geeks'. He should be able to create & manage new subcategories, pages and posts. But all new entries have to be assigned at minimum to his maincategory 'geeks'.
The next user is freak1 and has a maincategory 'freaks'. He should have the same behaviours than geek1 but with his main category. And so on with other users.
Do any one have an idea - or should I make my own plug-in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most powerful wordpress plugin for role management is "[Role Scoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/)". A more light-weight alternative would be "[Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/)".

If neither one of these two meets your requirements, look no further - then there isn't one.

You'd have to either write your own plugin or add the required functionality to your theme's [`functions.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Functions_File). You'd have to make use of the global variable `$current_user;` and check it either for role presence, usernames or user IDs. A snippet to get you started:

```
function restrict_current_user($query) {
    global $current_user;

    if ( in_array('substitute_the_user_role_here', $current_user->roles) ) {
        // do stuff here
    }

    if ( in_array('substitute_the_user_name_here', $current_user->user_login) ) {
        // do stuff here
    }

    // ID is an integer, no quotes around it:
    if ( in_array(substitute_the_user_ID_here, $current_user->ID) ) {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

The [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action might be a good one to hook into.

Answer (score 1):

This might be old news but, another option for what you're looking for could be s2Member.

http://www.s2Member.com

They have both free and paid models. Enjoy.